# How can I get url from java script ad line?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, childbrowser

I have one div when I click that div I want to open a child browser.I have the code for child browser but when I click the div it executes the javascript line and I didn't get any url from there.
Please check my code

Div code

```
  <div class="box_padding " onClick="window.open(this.href,'targetWindow','toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes);return false;" id="column-c-box-1" >

  <script type="text/javascript"  src="http://ad.leadboltads.net/show_app_ad.js?section_id=838333320"></script>

  </div>
```

when I tried this nothing happening.

So I have tried one more way to solve this issue

```
  function openwindow(){
            w=open("myurl",'windowname','width=600,height=250,scrollbars,resizable,toolbar,status');
            with(w.document){
                write("<body>");
                write("This is a new window");
                write("</body>");
            }
            return false;
        }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="box_padding "onClick="openwindow();" id="column-c-box-1" >
 <script type="text/javascript"  src="http://ad.leadboltads.net/show_app_ad.js?section_id=838333320"></script>
</div>
```

This is also not working.

Comment: Where in the code is the URL you want to pop up?

Comment: It doesn't appear that either "myurl" or this.href ever get a value. Are you trying to open the url src of the script tag?

Comment: @JanMisker  its a ad url ,we get that from this javascript code   <script type="text/javascript"  src="http://ad.leadboltads.net/show_app_ad.js?section_id=838333320"></script>

Comment: @sitesbyjoe  yes am tying to open url of the script  tag

Answer (score 1):

If you have jquery available you can use this instead of this.href:

```
$('script').attr('src');

function openwindow(){
            w=open($(this).find('script').attr('src'),'windowname','width=600,height=250,scrollbars,resizable,toolbar,status');
            with(w.document){
                write("<body>");
                write("This is a new window");
                write("</body>");
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: so i just need to change my method to something like above?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work in a preliminary test, native javascript. This would be trivial w/ jquery as a previous poster has shown.

Use the URL as a parameter in the div tag "srcVal".

```
<div class="box_padding " srcVal="http://ad.leadboltads.net/show_app_ad.js?section_id=838333320"  onClick="openwindow()" id="column-c-box-1">click me</div>
```

or this way:

```
<div class="box_padding "onClick="openwindow();" id="column-c-box-1" >
 <script type="text/javascript"  src="http://ad.leadboltads.net/show_app_ad.js?section_id=838333320" id="scriptTag"></script>
</div>
```

Your function slightly modified:

```
function openwindow(){
    var id = document.getElementById("column-c-box-1").getAttribute("srcVal");  
    //or
    // var scr = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
    //var id = scr[0].src; // use scr[scr - 1].src if have multiple scripts
               var w=open(id,'windowname','width=600,height=250,scrollbars,resizable,toolbar,status');
                with(w.document){
                    write("<body>");
                    write("This is a new window");
                    write("</body>");
                }
                return false;
            }
```

I used "with" because that is in your original code, but I'd caution against it.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FStatements%2Fwith

Comment: edited. had a bad "id" in there and fixed the second ref if wanting to use the "grab from script way"... though, that src took a veryyy long time to load. but eventually it did.